# Resnick - Probability Path - Exercise 5.24

Tags: probability, random-variables, lebesgue-integral

I'm struggling to solve the following problem from Resnick's book:

> Suppose $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$ are iid random variables with common N(0,1)
> distribution. Define:
>
> $Y_{n} = \frac{X_{1}}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}|}$.
>
> Use Fubini's theorem to verify that
>
> $E(Y_{n}) = 0$.
>
> Note as n $\rightarrow \infty$, $Y_{n} \rightarrow Y=\frac{X_{1}}{|X_{2}|}$
>
> and the expectation of Y doest not exist.

I've tried to attack the problem doing the following:

$E(Y_{n}) = \int_{\Omega_{Y_{n}}}Y_{n}dP = \int_{\Omega_{2}} \int_{\Omega_{1}}\frac{X_{1}}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}|} dP_{1}dP_{2} = \int_{\Omega_{2}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}|}  [\int_{\Omega_{1}} X_{1}dP_{1}]dP_{2} = \int_{\Omega_{2}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}|}  E[X_{1}]dP_{2}  = E[X_{1}]\int_{\Omega_{2}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+|X_{2}|}dP_{2} $

And then I got stuck at this part, since I don't know how to treat this Lebesgue integral.

Had the same problem on  finding E(Y), where $Y=\frac{X_{1}}{|X_{2}|}$

$E(Y) =E[X_{1}]\int_{\Omega_{2}}\frac{1}{|X_{2}|}dP_{2} $

How to solve this problem?

Why expectation of $Y_{n}$ exists, but not Y?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't ${\rm E}(X_1)=0$ ?

Comment: Why do you need to compute that? You already factored out $EX_1$ which is $0$!!

Comment: Well, that's for the fact that ${\rm E}(Y_n)=0$, but remains to prove that $Y_n$ has an expectancy :-)

Comment: I still can't see why $E(Y)$ does not exist, since the same should apply for it, since $E(X_{1}) = 0$. Why expectation of $Y_{n}$ exists, but not Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got $\mathbb E\left[X_n\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]\int_{\Omega_{2}}\frac{1}{\frac 1n+|X_{2}|}dP_{2}$. Since $\int_{\Omega_{2}}\frac{1}{\frac 1n+|X_{2}|}dP_{2}$ is finite for any fixed $n$ (the integrand is smaller than $n$), we get that $\mathbb E\left[X_n\right]=0$.

The expectation of $Y$ does not exist since $\mathbb E\left[\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert/\left\lvert X_2\right\rvert\right]$ is infinite. To see this, use Fubini's theorem to be reduced to prove that $\mathbb E\left[1/\left\lvert X_2\right\rvert\right]$ is infinite.